# How can I update values in the Blank Cells in the Excel sheet using HSSF using Java?

Tags: java, excel, automation, apache-poi

I have a workbook which contains several sheets where are there some data. At the end of the position, there will be a sheet which will not have the data for the very first time.

In this case, I have to update the data like this.

```
Test Suite Name: xxxxx
TestCase ID    Request1       Request2       Request3
1234567890     PASS            FAIL           PASS
```

For that I have written the code like this but its not performing as expected.

```
public void readAndUpdateBlankExcelCells()
{
    String xlPath = "D:\\working\\POC\\RunManager.xls"
    try
    {
        log.info ("Entered into Blank Method")
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(xlPath))

        HSSFWorkbook myBook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream)
        HSSFSheet sheet = myBook.getSheet("TestSuiteSummary")

        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;

        Iterator itr = sheet.rowIterator()
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            row = (HSSFRow) itr.next()
            System.out.println("Entered while loop")

            for (int idx = 0; idx < row.getLastCellNum(); idx++)
            {
                System.out.println("Entered for loop")
                cell = row.getCell(idx, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)
                cell.setCellValue("Test Suite Name: Sample Test Suite")
            }
            System.out.println()
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("In catch")
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

If its updated properly which I had mentioned in the above next TestSuite details should update in the next row...it will go for each test suite.

Can anyone tell me your suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: close both inputstream & mybook after each test suite execution

Comment: if I do so, will it update in the blank cells?

Comment: Did you try reading http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator ?

Comment: I don't understand how to use these codes in my requirement...Any suggestions please